# Retrieve row for each group having the maximum date

Tags: mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group, min

I have this MySQL table:

```
ID     Number     Date
1      4          2015-05-30
2      4          2016-03-15
3      5          2016-04-01
4      5          2016-05-01
```

I want to get unique Number but only get those with the highest date. The result must get ONLY:

```
ID     Number     Date
2      4          2016-03-15
4      5          2016-05-01
```

I tried:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM emp_events ee 
Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM emp_events ee1 WHERE ee1.Number = ee.Number));
```

but not getting all the desired results.

Comment: This question is asked and answered endlessly. Sometimes its answered correctly, so I guess it's just bad luck that none of the answers yet provided below suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can accomplish through `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
E.*
FROM emp_events E
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 
        Number,
        MAX(Date) max_date
    FROM emp_events ee 
    GROUP BY Number
) AS t
ON E.Number = t.Number AND E.Date = t.max_date
```

Another way could be using `IN`:

```
SELECT 
E.*
FROM emp_events E
WHERE (E.Number,E.Date) IN 
(
    SELECT 
        Number,
        MAX(Date) max_date
    FROM emp_events ee 
    GROUP BY Number
)
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try This

You have to `GROUP BY number` and also to find max date set `ORDER BY date ASC` in Query

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM(
    SELECT ee.*
    FROM `emp_events` AS ee
    ORDER BY ee.date ASC
) AS e
GROUP BY e.number
```

Comment: If you don't pass an aggregation function in your select, you will get mixed results for the order by.